# SQL Rolling Calculation by sequence

Tags: calculation

I am trying to build in another column that will SUM the Total Cost for the current SEQ row and all SEQ lines above.  I started with this but, it is only recognizing its own SEQ and not summing the additional SEQ.  I am sure there is a better way than the Case When or maybe I need to rework my Case When?

My goal is below:

SEQ100 = 100 rolling $100

SEQ200 =  50 rolling $150

SEQ300 = 400 Rolling $550

```
select 
DISTINCT J.JOB,
J.SUFFIX,
J.SEQ,
sum(J.PIECES_COMPLTD) as "Good Pcs",
sum(J.PIECES_SCRAP) as "Scrap",
sum(J.HOURS_WORKED) as "Hours Worked 'UNITS'",
sum(J.AMOUNT_LABOR) as "Labor and Material Amount",
sum(J.AMT_OVERHEAD) as "Overhead Amount",
sum(J.AMOUNT_LABOR + J.AMT_OVERHEAD) as "Total Cost",

sum(J.AMOUNT_LABOR + J.AMT_OVERHEAD) 
 OVER(PARTITION BY JOB ORDER BY J.SEQ) as "Rolling Total Cost by SEQ" 
    

FROM JOB_DETAIL AS J
WHERE J.JOB = '262223'
group by 
J.JOB,
J.SUFFIX
J.SEQ
ORDER BY J.JOB, J.SEQ;
```

Comment: The issue with your current approach is that the CASE statement is not correctly summing the values for the previous SEQ rows. Instead, it's just summing the value for the current SEQ row multiple times based on the conditions you've set.